# How can I set up a database that is able to import large amounts of data automatically on a daily basis?

Tags: database, import

I am new to databases and programming and am now supposed to create a database that can store large amounts of data. The critical problem to me is that i need to update the database everyday and add 150 sets of data to 60 different tables. The datasets all come in a different format though (.csv, .row, .sta...).

I would like to be able to create a GUI that can automatically import the datasets every day and update the tables. So far I have found a lot of info on exporting data from databases, not so much on importing data though.

Does someone have a pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given a reasonable definition of "best", what are your criteria? Is cost a major concern (I'm guessing not if you're considering Matlab, but maybe)? Is the UI for you only or are you turning end users loose on it? If end users, how smart/reliable are they? When you say manual import, do you mean a mostly automatic process that you occasionally manually initiate, or will it have to ask a lot of questions and have many different combinations?

I import lots of data daily and from different sources, I have to manually re-launch a process because a user has made a change and needs to see it reflected immediately, but but my set of defined sources doesn't change often. I've had good luck using the SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) tool in Microsoft's SQL Server. And it can certainly handle large amounts of data.

The basic functionality is you write a "package" that contains definitions of what your source is, how it's configured (i.e. if you are importing from a text file tell it the name and path, is it fixed field or delimited, what is the delimiter or width of each field, what field to skip, how many rows to skip, etc.), and where to put it (DB name and table, map fields, etc). I then set the schedule (mine are all overnight) in SQL agent, and it is all automatic from there unless something changes, in which case you edit your package to account for the changes.

I can also manually start any Package at any time and with very little effort.

And the range of imports sources is pretty impressive. I pull in data from CSV files, Lotus Notes, and DB2, and it's all automatic every night. It's also a fairly graphical "builder", which is frustrating for a hardcore coder, but if you're new to programming it's probably easier than a more code or script oriented approach.

Good luck, and welcome to the dark side. We have cookies.

Comment: Thank you Robert. The functionalities you are describing sound like they are exactly what I need. My problem right now is to get started and figure out which software is best to use. Also it would be great to get to find a free software. I am only considering Matlab since the program has already been bought.

Comment: Thank you Robert. The functionalities you are describing sound like they are exactly what I need. There are people who dont know anything about programming who just want to extract data. There are other users who are okay at programming, not great, who will help import the data. There will be about 10 different fileformats to import that arrive daily, so if i could write a package for each type, that would be perfect. My main problem right now is to get started and figure out which software is best to use, free would be awesome, if not we will buy a license. Hint please: "we have cookies"? ;-)

Comment: The SSIS solution is great except for one problem here - end users. It's great if you are doing it yourself, but it's not easy to give to your users and have them do it. You said you have Matlab, do you have any other programming languages available? Do you have a "real" database program available? By real I mean something like MS-SQL, MySQL, PostGres, DB2, etc., not Access or another "personal" database program. And the "we have cookies" was a joke, by referring to database programming as "the dark side" I was implying it was evil, but having cookies is nice so not very evil.

Comment: OK, I checked with our purchasing guy, and licensing for my development environment was about $1000 USD if that helps you put it in perspective. I looked at the MatLab documentation, and from what is visible without an account it does look like it can handle reading data from a file and writing it to a database, though I don't know it well enough to know if that is easy. I don't work with them, but I know there are high quality free solutions for both databases and programming languages, maybe for a starting point you could look at PostGreSQL and MySQL if you don't already have a database.